# How do i display all categories of a custom post type and have respective page for them?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I made a custom Post type named Blogs which is like this on the function.php

```
function blog_post() {
$labels = array(
'name'               => _x( 'Blogs', 'post type general name' ),
'singular_name'      => _x( 'Blog', 'post type singular name' ),
'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New Blog', 'blog' ),
'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Blogs' ),
'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Blog' ),
'new_item'           => __( 'New Blog' ),
'all_items'          => __( 'All Blogs' ),
'view_item'          => __( 'View Blog' ),
'search_items'       => __( 'Search Blogs' ),
'not_found'          => __( 'No blog found' ),
'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No blog found in the Trash' ), 
'parent_item_colon'  => '',
'menu_name'          => 'Blogs'
);
$args = array(
'labels'        => $labels,
'description'   => 'Holds blogs and blog specific data',
'public'        => true,
'menu_position' => 5,
'supports'      => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' ),
'has_archive'   => true,
);
 register_post_type( 'blogs', $args ); 
}
add_action( 'init', 'blog_post' );

function blog_categories() {
$labels = array(
'name'              => _x( 'Blog Categories', 'taxonomy general name' ),
'singular_name'     => _x( 'Blog Category', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
'search_items'      => __( 'Search Blog Categories' ),
'all_items'         => __( 'All Blogs Categories' ),
'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Blog Category' ),
'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Blog Category:' ),
'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Blog Category' ), 
'update_item'       => __( 'Update Blog Category' ),
'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Blog Category' ),
'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Blog Category' ),
'menu_name'         => __( 'Blog Categories' ),
);
 $args = array(
'labels' => $labels,
'hierarchical' => true,
);
register_taxonomy( 'blogs', 'blogs', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'blog_categories', 0 );
```

Now i created Post on the Blogs with Categories as **Who**, **Where** ,Now i want to have a page which displays all categories and when i click respective category name i want to have a page which shows pages as per the categories
So i wrote a code on archive-blogs.php

`<?php echo list_blog_categories($post->ID, 'blogs');?>`

The function for this is

```php
function list_blog_categories($postID, $term){
    $terms_list = wp_get_post_terms($postID, $term);
    $output = '';
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($terms_list as $term) { $i++;
        if( $i  > 1){ $output .= ', ';}
                $output .=  '<a href="'. get_term_link( $term ) . '">'. $term->name . '</a>';
    }
    return $output;
}
```

So the above code should display all my available categories and make a link out of it right? But it is not displaying all categories and making a respective link for each type of category
I was expecting like this : http://localhost/homekong/blogs/{Category}
But this is not working 
So i am super confused about this can someone please help me out

Comment: Your code seems fine. But, 1) Why don't you just use [`the_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_terms/)? `<?php the_terms( $post->ID, 'blogs' ); ?>`; 2) You should use a different rewrite *base* slug for the `blogs` *taxonomy*. Otherwise, visiting single `blogs` taxonomy term page would result in 404 error.

Comment: changed the taxonomy name to blog-category
But i still can't figure out what i should do to have separate pages for each categories like Who, Where
How do i achieve sitelink/blog-category/{who/where} 
Should i make a new page like archive-slug.php or something like that i cant figure a way out how do i do that

Comment: Currently i am using archive-blogs.php

Comment: Have you created a custom [taxonomy template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/taxonomy-templates/) (e.g. `taxonomy-blog-category.php` in your case)?

Comment: Not yet oh was that the case?

Comment: So what i did was changed the taxonomy name from blogs to blog-category
Now added taxonomy-blog-category page and added the content of archive page. When i try to view the category page from the admin menu then it says page cant be found

Comment: Have you flushed the rewrite rules? (because you've changed the taxonomy slug) Just visit the permalink settings page..

Comment: Welp sorry i hadnt added the category page so that was the issue. Thanks a lot for helping me outt :D
I am new to wordpress lot to learn :D

Comment: Can i ask one last question?

Comment: So how do i get the link of each categories for my <a href ? 
I tried doing get_category_link() but its not doing it 
The structure is like this 
echo "<li>" . '<a href="<?php echo get_category_link($term);?>" class="active">' . $term->name . '</a>' . "</li>";

Comment: You're concatenating the string, so you should do `"<li>" . '<a href="' . get_category_link( $term ) . '" class="active">' . $term->name . '</a>' . "</li>"` instead of what you've tried. I.e. No `<?php echo` and `;?>`, and the function call should *not* be in quotes - `function()` and not `"function()"` or `'function()'`.

Comment: Thanks a lot this will do :D